# NSOpenPanel not open and not working in swift 4 OS x app

Tags: macos, nsopenpanel

**Swift 4 / Xcode 9.2 / OS X 10.12**

I am trying to use a NSOpenPanel to get a jpg/png file with the following code, but not able to open panel for choose image, no crash, nothing happened.

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["jpg","png"]

openPanel.beginSheetModal(for: self.view.window!) { (result) in

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Give your app access to user selected files under

**Capabilities** -> **App Sandbox** -> **File Access** -> **User Selected File**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 9 apps are sandboxed by default.

You have to enable `Read/Write` access of *User Selected File* in the Capabilities tab

[image]